# How to compare id's in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have 'article' and 'user' models with m2m relationship (pivot table with user_id and article_id columns).
In ArticleController i need to check is user the one of authors of the article to have access perform update/delete operations with article.
I can take currently logged user id from auth->user()->id.

Comment: Please include your current code, so we can see what is there currently. It is hard for people to assist you on SO if you do not include your code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use Laravel policies
i suggest you to take a look at this documentation
[Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization)

Answer (score 0):

If you using standard Eloquent-relationship as per https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Just simply get the article first then check if it has relation with the authenticated user.

```
$article = Article::find($id);
if ($article->users()->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->count() ) {
     //your code
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get users() from article table?

Comment: yes. it is possible if you have defined many to many relationship between the article and the user. the return will be list user that related with that article.

Answer (score 0):

I used policies with such algorithm inside. Thx for help.

```
public function update(User $user, Article $article){
    //All articles id where user is author.
    $userArticles = UserArticle::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

    $confirmFlag = false; //check flag.
    //We compare article ids that belong to user with article id that we want to edit.
    foreach ($userArticles as $userArticle) {
        if ($userArticle->article_id != $article->id) {
            $confirmFlag = false;
        } else {
            $confirmFlag = true;
            break; // if we found that article that we want to edit
            // is belong to user then we break our foreach with $confirmFlag=true.
        }
    }
    return $confirmFlag == true ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your own answer , I want to give you a better approach ...

```
public function update(User $user, Article $article){
//All articles id where user is author.
  $userArticles = UserArticle::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('article_id', $article->id)->first();

  return $userArticles === null ? false : true;
}
```